# Network always predicts same class on different test samples

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to predict a single MNIST image from the trained model I saved after training. However whenever I try to print the prediction (the classification variable at the end), I get "0" for every different image I enter. I looked online, but could only find evaluation of the model, and not how to predict a single thing. Please show me if possible in documentation or the method of doing so.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
batch_size = 128
test_size = 256

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))

def model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden):
    l1a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, w,                       # l1a shape=(?, 28, 28, 32)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l1 = tf.nn.max_pool(l1a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l1 shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, p_keep_conv)

    l2a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l1, w2,                     # l2a shape=(?, 14, 14, 64)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l2 = tf.nn.max_pool(l2a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l2 shape=(?, 7, 7, 64)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l2 = tf.nn.dropout(l2, p_keep_conv)

    l3a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l2, w3,                     # l3a shape=(?, 7, 7, 128)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l3 = tf.nn.max_pool(l3a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l3 shape=(?, 4, 4, 128)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l3 = tf.reshape(l3, [-1, w4.get_shape().as_list()[0]])    # reshape to (?, 2048)
    l3 = tf.nn.dropout(l3, p_keep_conv)

    l4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l3, w4))
    l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, p_keep_hidden)

    pyx = tf.matmul(l4, w_o)
    return pyx

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
trX = trX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img
teX = teX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])

w = init_weights([3, 3, 1, 32])       # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
w2 = init_weights([3, 3, 32, 64])     # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
w3 = init_weights([3, 3, 64, 128])    # 3x3x32 conv, 128 outputs
w4 = init_weights([128 * 4 * 4, 625]) # FC 128 * 4 * 4 inputs, 625 outputs
w_o = init_weights([625, 10])         # FC 625 inputs, 10 outputs (labels)

p_keep_conv = tf.placeholder("float")
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float")
py_x = model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x, labels=Y))
train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).minimize(cost)
predict_op = tf.argmax(py_x, 1)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you need to initialize all variables
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    for i in range(100):
        training_batch = zip(range(0, len(trX), batch_size),
                             range(batch_size, len(trX)+1, batch_size))
        for start, end in training_batch:
            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end],
                                          p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})

        test_indices = np.arange(len(teX)) # Get A Test Batch
        np.random.shuffle(test_indices)
        test_indices = test_indices[0:test_size]

        print(i, np.mean(np.argmax(teY[test_indices], axis=1) ==
                         sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: teX[test_indices],
                                                         Y: teY[test_indices],
                                                         p_keep_conv: 1.0,
                                                         p_keep_hidden: 1.0})))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

#### Here is the code I wrote in order to be able to predict a single image, but the "classification" returns "0". Shouldn't it return the index of the hot encoding?

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
    print "...Model Loaded..."
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(predict_op, -1), feed_dict={X: trX[26].reshape(1,28,28,1),p_keep_conv: 1.0,p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
    print classification
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize your variables after loading/restoring (`tf.global_variables_initializer().run()`). Otherwise, your trained variables will be overridden.

**Edit**:

Also, `sess.run(tf.argmax(predict_op, -1), ...` is using `predict_op = tf.argmax(py_x, 1)`.
This should be changed to only one argmax operation:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, "tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("...Model Loaded...")
    # tf.global_variables_initializer().run()  # <-- do not run this
    classification = sess.run(predict_op,  # <-- no second argmax
                              feed_dict={X: teX[26].reshape(1,28,28,1),  # <-- use test set
                                         p_keep_conv: 1.0,
                                         p_keep_hidden: 1.0}
                              )
    print(classification)
```

Also, you might want to test on the test set (teX, teY) instead of the training set (trX, trY).

Comment: I'm still getting 0 after commenting this line.

Comment: --> saver = tf.train.Saver(), "ValueError: No variables to save". I get this Exception with your code (tf v1.4). Did you call model() before this line? If so, would you provide a MWE?

Comment: I cant provide anything minimal more than this, it is working fine, till the end. The output is just wrong.

Comment: This is not a MWE. For instance, you don't provide information for when and how you actually call `init_weights()` and `model()`. :)

Comment: Edited it and added the missing lines.

Comment: @MasterWizard if this information was helpful, please consider marking it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the error was:

```
classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(predict_op, -1),
                          feed_dict={X: teX[2].reshape(1,28,28,1),
                                     p_keep_conv: 1.0,
                                     p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
```

should be:

```
classification = sess.run(predict_op,
                          feed_dict={X: teX[2].reshape(1,28,28,1),
                                     p_keep_conv: 1.0,
                                     p_keep_hidden: 1.0})
```